# Changing class by jquery but not reflecting at html view side

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am suffering from a very strange problem. I am using Jquery to change classes of multiple element. I am doing it by a for loop at js side. On clicking on element it changes the classes to show 'selected' and changes background. But it is not actually changes the view.

The strange thing is that I am not able to see the changes at view side but when I have consoled the elements it was having the classes.

HTML SIDE

```
<li id="1469532600" class="slot ng-binding ng-scope time-slot" ng-repeat="slot in timeSlots">17:00</li>
```

CONSOLED ELEMENT

[image]

I am not able to find the exact solution...

Comment: Please post you CSS and javascript code. Better create a fiddle to replicate your problem. And why are you using JQuery to change class try ng-class instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use angular way to change class name like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<style>
.selected{color:green;}
</style>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names=[
{name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
{name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
{name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}];

$scope.makeSelect = function(index){
 
  $scope.names[index].selected = true;
}
});


</script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="">

<p>Looping with objects:</p>
<ul>
  <li ng-class="names[$index].selected==true ? 'selected':''" ng-repeat="x in names" ng-click="makeSelect($index);">
  {{ x.name + ', ' + x.country + '------'+x.selected }}</li>
</ul>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```